# Tick student's marks that belongs to the first quartile

Tags: google-sheets, formula, percentile, google-sheets-formula

In the spreadsheet, there is information about student's marks. This is an example of it:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw2rW.png)

[image: Table]

[Shared table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u-9DmmuFL8iV4KTdaJp-9ehQd5f8JGFJ2z9p7bRPHWo/edit)

In column C I want to work out whether the student's mark is among the 25% top marks on his/her class.

The expected output is in red. I want to obtain such output using formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try in C2 and copied down to suit:

```
=if(B2>=percentile(B$2:B$51;0,75);"YES";"NO")
```

I hope your classes are no bigger than 50.